# Laravel database returns undefined index error

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, connection

I am developing a project using laravel  5.6.18 framework. In my database.php file I get the following error:

> "Undefined index: driver"

And my connection is as following:

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],  
],
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a database driver either in the env file. What did you set as the database driver in your env file?
here

```
DB_CONNECTION=driver
```

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql

Comment: check in config/database.php what is the default connection?

Comment: 'layouts' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

Comment: change layouts to default  it should be like this 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),